# Get Key Value pair after String Split

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, split

I have a string in the form

Key=asdf, num=90, Key=ert, num=20, Key=yged, num=20, Key=kned, num=35

I have to filter only Key num pairs which has value 20 and store them into a Key Value pair such that Key=ert, num=20 will be first record and Key=yged, num=20 will be second record so on. How can I use Map in JavaScript so that always first value will go as key and second will go as value and form pairs in this case. I have used the following :

```
var dataString = JSON.parse(data).data;
    var arrayVal = new Array();
    arrayVal = dataString.split(', ');
    for(a in arrayVal){
      console.log(arrayVal[a]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` probably isn't the best tool for the job here. `Array.reduce` would be a better approach. Since you know what your delimiters are (namespaces and equal signs), you can logically split things up so that you know that every other iteration will give you a key/value. You can then create a mechanism to track what the last key is so you can map the value to it.

```js
const str = 'Key=asdf, num=90, Key=ert, num=20, Key=yged, num=20, Key=kned, num=35';
const arr = str.split(', ').reduce( (acc, curr) => {
  const entry = curr.split('=');
  const key = entry[0];
  const val = entry[1];
  if (key === 'Key') {
    acc['last_key'] = val
    acc[val] = null;
  } else if (key === 'num') {
    acc[acc['last_key']] = val;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
delete arr.last_key;
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my say

```
const dataString = JSON.parse(data).data;
const arrayVal = dataString.split(', ');
const obj = {}; // initialize the object

for (let i = 0; i < arrayVal.length; i += 2) { // Iterating over two elements for the key and value
    const key = arrayVal[i].split('=')[1];
    const value = arrayVal[i + 1].split('=')[1]; 

    obj[key] = value;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It's kinda ugly.

```
let result = dataString.split(', ')
                .map((value, index, array) =>
                    value === 'num=20' && array[index - 1])
                .filter(x => x);
console.log(result);
```